# extern Template from function in Class

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пробую унести из декларации класса Template в реализацию, все попытки приводят к ругани компилятора, не совсем понимаю как работает в этом случае extern

a.hpp

```
 class A
 {
    public:
       template<typename T> bool func1(T *val);
       extern template <> bool func1<char>(char *val);
       extern template <> bool func1<wchar_t>(wchar_t *val);
```

a.cpp

```
  template<typename T>
  A::func1(T *val) {.. реализация..}
```

test.cpp

```
  char *val = ...alloc();
  A a = new A();
  a->func1(val);
```

В мануалах вроде так-же, но ошибок это инциирует море..

Comment: "В мануалах вроде так-же..." Это в каких же "мануалах" вы такое увидели?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы такое пытаетесь выписать. Синтаксис `template <>` - это синтаксис *явной специализации*. Но в явной специализации не может быть такого `extern`.

Если это попытка выполнить *явное инстанцирование*, то в синтаксисе явного инстанцирования не должно быть никаких `<>`. Ключевое слово `extern` в явном инстанцировании говорит о том, что это лишь *предварительное объявление* данного явного инстанцирования, а само явное инстанцирование будет выполнено вами где-то в одном из файлов реализации. Располагаться такое объявление должно за пределами класса

```
// a.hpp

class A
{
public:
   template<typename T> bool func1(T *val);
};

extern template bool A::func1<char>(char *val);
extern template bool A::func1<wchar_t>(wchar_t *val);
```

Еще раз: это никак не отменяет необходимости выполнять само явное инстанцирование в `.cpp` файле (то же самое без `extern`). Там, где видно определение инстанцируемого метода

```
// a.cpp

template<typename T>
bool A::func1(T *val) { /* реализация */ }

template bool A::func1<char>(char *val);
template bool A::func1<wchar_t>(wchar_t *val);
```

---

Предварительное объявление явного инстанцирования с `extern` - необязательный шаг. Это делается чисто ради оптимизации процесса трансляции, когда такая оптимизация возможна и нужна.

Делать предварительное объявление явного инстанцирования имеет смысл тогда, когда полное *определение* основного шаблона видно всем подряд, т.е. располагается в заголовочном файле. Без предварительного объявления явного инстанцирования компилятор будет честно инстанцировать этот шаблон во всех единицах трансляции, а потом линкер устранит все лишние инстанцирования, оставив только ваше явное. Вот для того, чтобы избежать выполнения этой бессмысленной лишней работы и служит предварительное объявление явного инстанцирования с `extern` - оно говорит компилятору: "Не инстанцируй данную версию шаблона, не создавай линкеру лишнюю работу. Эта версия шаблона уже и так где-то инстанцирована пользователем, линкер ее найдет".

Но в вашем случае определение основного шаблона скрыто - оно спрятано в `.cpp` файл. Это означает, что компилятор никак не сможет инстанцировать этот шаблон в других единицах трансляции, даже если захочет. В такой ситуации проблемы множественного инстанцирования в разных единицах трансляции нет вообще. Делать предварительное объявление явного инстанцирования с `extern` никакого смысла нет - оно ничего не даст. Строчки с `extern` в вашем случае можно просто выбросить.